# Electron automatically adds 'Hide Tab Bar' and 'Show all Tabs' to 'View' menu on macOS

Tags: macos, electron, menuitem

I construct a application menu like this:

```js
const template = [
  {
    label: app.name,
    submenu: [
      /* ... */
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "File",
    submenu: [
      /* ... */
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "View",
    submenu: [{role: "togglefullscreen"}]
  },
];

// ...
Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplte(template));
```

The issue is, the "Hide Tab Bar" and "Show All Tabs" items appear in the "View" menu's submenu, even though I don't specify that they should.

[image: Picture of View menu of electron app]

If I change the menu's name to anything else (e.g. "Viewx" or "Vie" or even "view") those items no longer appear.

How do I prevent this? I've done some searching but have not seen this behavior documented anywhere. I'm testing on macOS, have not tried reproducing on other OSes.

Comment: What is version of electron you are using

Comment: @HồngPhúc 19.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the fact that I was showing the dev tools -- `mainView.webContents.openDevTools()`

The dev tools have a tab bar. When I stopped showing the dev tools, those extra items in the View menu were no longer added.